# Running etherpad-lite on subdirectory with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdirectory, referenceerror, etherpad

I have running etherpad-lite 1.5.7 on my server. It is accessible unter `http:\\myserver:9001`, but I want to access it under `https:\\myserver\pad`.

I configured nginx like this

```
location /pad {
    rewrite /pad/(.*) /$1 break;
    rewrite ^/pad$ /pad/ permanent;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_redirect / /pad/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
}

location /pad/socket.io {
    rewrite /pad/socket.io/(.*) /socket.io/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
    proxy_redirect / /pad/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X‐Real‐IP $remote_addr; # http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule
    proxy_set_header X‐Forwarded‐For $remote_addr; # EP logs to show the actual remote I
    proxy_set_header Host $host; # pass the host header
    proxy_http_version 1.1; # recommended with keepalive connections
    # WebSocket proxying ‐ from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 }

location /static {
    rewrite /static/(.*) /static/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

But when opening a pad I get following error in the log file

```
^[[33m[2016-03-06 13:05:15.308] [WARN] client - ^[[39mUncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined -- { errorId: 'BCdMZzVXqx5Df5TwGUz5',
msg: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined',
url: 'https://myserver/pad/p/Testpad',
linenumber: 232,
userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36' }
```

Firefox says

```
https://myserver/pad/socket.io/socket.io.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
pad.js?callback=require.define:232 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

The admin panel can't show the settings file or the plugins.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I just got my installation to work with the following, so it is still little untested. This assumes you are running Etherpad-lite under https and reverse proxied to localhost with nginx.

```
location /pad/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
    rewrite /pad(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header        Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
}
location /pad { rewrite /pad /pad/ permanent; }
location /static/ { include /etc/nginx/proxy_conf; proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/static/ ;}
```